# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un vector (matriz) en un archivo y leerlo de vuelta?

Tags: c++, array

Me gustaría saber como puedo guardar una matriz compuesta de vectores, esta únicamente guardara números, o en algún caso especial caracteres, lo que intento es así.

```
Tablero<int>tableroEP(filasEP, columnasEP, 0); //Creo el tablero, asigno por defecto un 0 en todas las posiciones

tableroEP.mostrarMatriz(tableroEP.getMatriz()); //Imprime la matriz en pantalla

ofstream mapa("Tabler.txt", ios::app);

size_t sz = sizeof (tableroEP);
songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz));
songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tableroEP[0]), sz * sizeof(tableroEP[0]));
```

De momento la puedo guardar así, pero como guardo el objeto, el archivo no tiene algo legible para asegurarme de que esta bien escrito, lo encontré en internet, pero cómo puedo leerla y asignarla a un nueva matriz para imprimirla después?. Existe una manera más sencilla de hacer este proceso?, es para una actividad escolar, un busca minas.

**Esta es mi clase Tablero:**

```
 template<class T>
 class Tablero
 {
vector<vector<T>> *matriz;
int fila_;
int columna_;
public:
Tablero();
Tablero(int filas, int columas);
Tablero(int filas, int columas, const T &dato);

vector<vector<T>> &getMatriz();
vector<T> &operator[](int fila);

void mostrarArreglo(const vector<T> &arreglo);
void mostrarMatriz(const vector<vector<T>> &matriz);
};

template<class T>
Tablero<T>::Tablero()
{
matriz = new vector<vector<T>> (3, vector<T>(3)); //< FILAS - COLUMNAS
fila_ = columna_ = 3;
}

template<class T>
Tablero<T>::Tablero(int filas, int columas)
{
 matriz = new vector<vector<T>> (filas, vector<T>(columas)); //< FILAS -  COLUMNAS
fila_ = filas;
columna_ = columas;
}

template<class T>
Tablero<T>::Tablero(int filas, int columas, const T &dato)
{
   matriz = new vector<vector<T>> (filas, vector<T>(columas, dato)); //< FILAS - COLUMNAS - DATO
    fila_ = filas;
    columna_ = columas;
}

 template<class T>
 vector<vector<T>> &Tablero<T>::getMatriz()
 {
   return *matriz;
 }

  template<class T>
  vector<T> &Tablero<T>::operator[](int fila)
 {
    if (fila > fila_) {
        throw out_of_range("Fila no valida, [] Tablero");
 }
   return (*matriz)[fila];
 }

  template<class T>
 void Tablero<T>::mostrarArreglo(const vector<T> &arreglo)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); ++i) {
       cout << "\t" << arreglo[i];
   }
}

template<class T>
void Tablero<T>::mostrarMatriz(const vector<vector<T>> &matriz)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < matriz.size(); ++i) {
       mostrarArreglo(matriz[i]);
       cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de proponerte una solución, prefiero responder por qué no te funciona tu código:

> ```
> size_t sz = sizeof (tableroEP);
> songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz));
> songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tableroEP[0]), sz * sizeof(tableroEP[0]));
> ```
>
> De momento la puedo guardar así, pero como guardo el objeto, el archivo no tiene algo legible.

En ese código tienes una cosa bien y una cosa mal.

#### Datos y contenedor no son lo mismo.

Cuando llamas al operador de indexado (`operator[]`) de tu clase plantilla `Tablero` estás devolviendo una referencia a un `vector` interno y pretendes escribir este `vector` en el archivo. Para hacerte una idea de cuán equivocada es la idea, es como si para saber lo cargado que va un camión de mudanzas pesaras el camión entero cuando quieres pesar sólo el contenido del remolque.

Cometes el error mencionado dos veces, la primera al considerar que el tamaño de tus datos es el tamaño del tablero (el tamaño del camión no es el tamaño del contenido de su remolque) y la segunda al considerar el `vector` como el dato a almacenar.

Si guardas el `vector` como en tu código estarás guardando la representación binaria del mismo, no los datos que maneja. Suponiendo que tu `vector` sea el `std::vector` de la STL, puedes acceder al puntero a los datos almacenados mediante la función [`std::vector::data` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data); eso es lo que quieres guardar:

```
auto tamanyo = tableroEP[0].size() * sizeof(T);
songsList.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(tableroEP[0].data()), tamanyo);
```

#### La función `write` escribe datos en crudo.

La función [`std::basic_ostream::write` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) te permite escribir datos en binario (en realidad guarda caracteres, pero puede usarse para guardar la representación binaria de un objeto), así que no esperes abrir el objeto y ver algo legible a no ser que uses un [visor hexadecimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_hexadecimal).

#### Propuesta.

Para empezar, olvida la memoria dinámica en tu clase `Tablero`, además de no necesitarla la pides en tus constructores pero no la liberas en ningún destructor. Crea los vectores internos usando el segundo constructor de [`std::vector` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
template<typename T>
struct Tablero
{
    using fila_t = std::vector<T>;
    using tabla_t = std::vector<fila_t>;

    Tablero() : Tablero(3, 3) {}
    //          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Constructor delegado
    Tablero(int filas, int columas) :
        filas_(filas), columnas_(columnas),
        matriz(filas, fila_t(columnas))
    {}
    Tablero(int filas, int columas, const T &dato) :
        filas_(filas), columnas_(columnas),
        matriz(filas, fila_t(columnas, dato))
    {}

    tabla_t &getMatriz();
    fila_t &operator[](int fila);

private:
    tabla_t matriz;
    int filas_;
    int columnas_;
};
```

Con esta aproximación evitarás el tedio de manejar la memoria manualmente y también evitarás el problema de generar [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria) como estabas generando.

En cuanto a escritura y lectura en archivo, te aconsejo crear unas funciones `save` y `load`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Tablero
{
    void save(const std::string file_name)
    {
        if (std::ofstream file{file_name})
        {
            // Guardar filas
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&filas_), sizeof(filas_));
            // Guardar columnas
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&columnas_), sizeof(columnas_));
            // Guardar datos
            for (const auto &fila : matriz)
                file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(fila.data()), fila.size() * sizeof(T));
        }
    }
    void load(const std::string file_name)
    {
        if (std::ifstream file{file_name})
        {
            // Leer filas
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&filas_), sizeof(filas_));
            // Leer columnas
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&columnas_), sizeof(columnas_));
            // Reajustar tamaños
            matriz.resize(filas, fila_t(columnas_));
            for (auto &fila : matriz) fila.resize(columnas_);
            // Leer datos
            for (auto &fila : matriz)
                for (auto &dato : fila)
                    file.read(reinterpert_cast<char *>(&dato, sizeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí pensaba sobre la fuga de memoria pero no sabía resolverlo, me sirvió perfecto, sólo tengo dos dudas, en "tabla matriz;", te refieres a "tabla_"? y, cuando leo el archivo, los datos leídos se asignan a la matriz que tiene la clase?. @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: +1. Siempre es un gusto leer sus respuestas.

Comment: Exactamente... @Xam

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer un método para llamar al constructor?, o cómo puedo llamarlo desde fuera?. Ejemplo: `int x; void miMetodo(){ x = 3; }`, se puedo hacer eso con los constructores?

Comment: @OscarD 1) Tienes razón, `tabla matriz;` es `tabla_t matriz;`, me despisté (lo corrijo). 2) Dado que las funciones `load` y `save` serían de la clase, los datos leídos se asignan, efectivamente, ala matriz que tiene la clase.

Comment: @OscarD No se a qué te refieres con "*un método para llamar al constructor*". El constructor se llama con `nombre_de_la_clase(parámetros);`.